# How to abort youtube-dl download if file grows above a certain size in Python

Tags: python, youtube-dl

In python, is it possible to stop a youtube-dl download if it becomes larger than a specified size?

I am using youtube_dl imported into python:

```py
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(urls)
```

Is it possible to stop the .download() function early if it gets too big?

Comment: @larsks I'm not using `requests`. I am importing `youtube_dl`. I updated my question.

Comment: Maybe you want the `max_filesize` option? It's documented [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/downloader/common.py#L46).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @larsks said in the comments,
adding `max_filesize` to the `ydl_opts` works

```py
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
  'max_filesize': <number_of_bytes>
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(urls)
```